# Securing Communication between Kubernetes Microservices within Azure Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

We have deployed our Micro-services in Azure Kubernetes Services using Dockers and it has a InGress Controller to route the calls.
ref:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress

We are protecting the public end point with a SSL Certificate but We want to know is there a way to encrypt the communication happening within the Kubernetes Clusters i.e. between Micro-services. Most of the Microsoft documentation was referring to Nginx implmenetations and nothing beyond that..

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks in advance,

Regards
JK

Comment: Your best best probably use a service mesh for ex. Istio/LinkerD (https://istio.io/blog/2017/0.1-auth/) or build on your own

Comment: As Vishal Biyani pointed out, using Service Mesh will save you lots of effort from manually generating certificates, signing, and distributing them; moreover, it provides many awesome benefits like: fault injecting, rate limiting, multiple version app traffic routing, etc.

You can checkout their tutorials on how to set up on Azure here: https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/platform-setup/azure/.

However, you can do things the hard way: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/cluster-administration/certificates/

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/managing-tls-in-a-cluster/

Comment: Also, I think this tutorial will help you.

https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/secure-kubernetes-services-with-ingress-tls-letsencrypt/

Disclaimer: I have not tried this tutorial.